# SharePoint 2013 Quick Launch Error "the given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: error, navigation, hyperlink

We have currently the error

> The given key was not present in the dictionary

if a user clicks on the link "Edit Links" on the Quick Launch list.

I as admin can see the whole navigation. Has anybody an idea what the error could be?

[image: here you can see the error]

Here's the ULS Log entry:

> PortalSiteMapProvider was unable to fetch children for node at URL:
>   /teams/co_group, message: The given key was not present in the
>   dictionary., stack trace:    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserResource.GetValueForUICulture(CultureInfo
>   cultureInfo)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedUserResource..ctor(SPUserResource
>   userResource, CultureInfo defaultCulture, String defaultValue)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.SPNavigationSiteMapNode.CreateSPNavigationSiteMapNode(PortalWebSiteMapNode
>   webNode, SPNavigationNode node, PortalSiteMapNode parentNode)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.ProcessSPNavigationNode(SPNavigationNode
>   node, SPNavigationNode previousSibling, PortalSi...

BR Michael

Comment: I have the same error. anybody can help? Error: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary. at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserResource.GetValueForUICulture(CultureInfo cultureInfo) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedUserResource..ctor(SPUserResource userResource, CultureInfo defaultCulture, String defaultValue) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.SPNavigationSiteMapNode.CreateSPNavigationSiteMapNode(PortalWebSiteMapNode webNode, SPNavigationNode node, PortalSiteMapNod

Comment: Is the navigation based upon managed navigation? I have seen this error with users with incorrect permissions on the managed metadata

Comment: We don't have managed navigation for the side links. 
It is also very interesting that we as admin can see the navigation always (also when the error occurs). If i change the navigation e.g. I'm adding a new link, the user is sometimes abla to see the side navigation again.

Comment: I added some more information to this case - maybe somebody has a solution for the problem. 
Thanks Michael

Answer (score 1):

We've the same Issue, but only at at sites where 3 languages are activated.
If we have enabled: english, Germany, France and deactivate France, quick Navigation is working again